# Define custom DNS server when looking up host

Tags: dns, php

I'm having trouble with my current web host's DNS server which doesn't correctly resolve IP addresses for Baidu.

```
shell_exec('host -W 2 180.76.5.168');
shell_exec('nslookup 180.76.5.168');
```

Is there a way I can define my own DNS server address when trying to resolve the host?

Quoted output of my localhost result...

> host: baiduspider-180-76-5-168.crawl.baidu.com
>
> Server: Wireless_Broadband_Router.home Address: 192.168.1.1 Name:
>   baiduspider-180-76-5-168.crawl.baidu.com Address: 180.76.5.168

Comment: What is trying to resolve the name?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The IP "180.76.5.168" *should* resolve to "baiduspider-180-76-5-168.crawl.baidu.com" which means I can verify that this and other IP addresses are legitimate Baidu search engines.

Comment: That's... not what I asked.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I think you're referring to this: http://php.net/shell_exec ?

Comment: That function doesn't resolve anything. Are you saying that you run external executables that perform name resolution?

Comment: I'm saying I'm looking for anything in the Linux shell (that is hopefully installed by default) that would let me specify the IP of the DNS address in addition to the IP that I'm trying to resolve. I'm accessing the shell via PHP so as long as `shell_exec`.

Comment: The only way to change it for anything in the shell is to change the system resolver. This cannot be done in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way I can define my own DNS server address when trying to
>   resolve the host?

Yes, we can using following method .

Method #1 - All Method trying to resolve from Google Public DNS, you can change as you wish.

```
nslookup  180.76.5.168  8.8.8.8
```

Method #2

```
dig -x 180.76.5.168 @8.8.8.8
```

Method #3

```
host -W 2 180.76.5.168  8.8.8.8
```

Comment: This worked great! `$p = trim(trim(explode(' pointer',shell_exec('host -W 2 180.76.5.168  68.238.96.12'))[1]),'.');` Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On a Unix system there is a file called `nsswitch.conf` which controls how names of various things get resolved. For example, host names would be governed by this line in that file:

```
hosts:      files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

This line says:

- Look to "files" first (such as `/etc/hosts`).
- Next try "mdns4_minimal" which means try to resolve the name using Multicast DNS.
- The "NOTFOUND" means that any response of notfound by the preceeding mdns4_minimal process should be treated as authoritative and that the system should not try to continue hunting for an answer.
- Lastly the "dns" parameter means to use a legacy unicast DNS query.

When the name is attempting to be resolved via mdns4_minimal the file `/etc/resolv.conf` will be consulted to determine things such as:

- nameservers to query
- default search domain name
- default domain name

For example:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
domain somedom.net.
search somedom.net.
nameserver 192.168.1.101
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

So to control your default DNS server outside of the options that @RahulPatil listed in his answer you'll need to change the DNS server in your `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

#### References

- [Network Configuration - Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html)

Comment: This looks good but my question was in the context of web development with the ability to access a different DNS server on a shared server. It does look like this would be very useful to someone else though, thanks for answering.